# .rrr subscript for float type

Tags: shaders, hlsl

I'm a little confused with this construction:

```
float sdcolor = MyColor.r; // MyColor has float4 type
float rcolor = sdcolor.rrr; // .ggg or .bbb isn't working

return float4(rcolor , rcolor , rcolor , 1);
```

Hence the question: how it's possible to subscript **anything** from a float type? What is the meaning of the `.rrr` subscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HLSL, scalar values behave like 1-dimensional vectors.  They have a `.x` component, or equivalently a `.r` component.  Writing `.xxx` or `.rrr` is just a way of converting a scalar into a vector, in this case a `float3`, by duplicating that component.

```
float3 rgb;
float gray = dot(rgb, 0.333.xxx);         // You can do it on literal constants
rgb = lerp(rgb, gray.xxx, desaturation);  // And on scalars
```

It's usually not necessary to do this, as HLSL is pretty good about automatically converting scalars to vectors where needed.  It's more of a stylistic choice; some shader authors do this to make the conversion explicit, even if it's not required by the language.

Comment: You said that `.xxx` converts a scalar into a vector, but in my example I'd assigned `sdcolor.rrr` (which is `float3`) to the one-dimensional `rcolor`. I still can't understand how it's possible.

Comment: @RomanChehowsky Yeah, that's kinda pointless, since it's converting it to a vector and then right back to a scalar.  Actually, you should be getting an "implicit truncation of vector type" warning there, at least with more recent versions of the compiler.